# function delete_img didn't work

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I followed the link
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Working-with-databases

All works except the function `del_img()`

```
function delete_img($delimg)
{
    $delete_from_db = $this->query("DELETE FROM files WHERE file = '$delimg'") or die(mysql_error());
    return $delete_from_db;
}
```

I dont understand why it's not working

Comment: From where do you call your delete_img function? Please provide some more code and an error message (if available)

Comment: no, I dont found the erro sql
but I see 

The requested method DELETE is not allowed for the URL /demo2/blueimp-6.9.6/server/php/files/426757817.jpg.

Comment: from the function delete, i called the funtion del_img if it is succeed

public function delete($print_response = true) {
   .....
    if ($success) {
        $this->delete_img($file_name);
       ......
    }
    return $this->generate_response($info, $print_response);
}